# Nodejs/Javascript output written to all files instead of individual

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm learning nodejs/javascript. I have an app that basically merges translation files. I have an english.pot file and multiple translated files, Spanish.po French.po German.po etc. I get all the .po files that exist and process each one outputting the merge into a new file Spansh.po.new. My code works fine when I have just 1 .po file which is how I have been developing it for ease. I added the other 2 .po files and now I get the 3 .new files but they all have the same output which is a merge of all of them.

With 1 .po file

```
msgid "Visit plugin homepage"
msgstr "Besuchen Sie die Plugin-Homepage"

#. translators: %s: plugin author
msgid "by %s"
msgstr "von %s"
```

With more than 1 .po file all 3 .new files look like this

```
msgid "Visit plugin homepage"
msgstr "Besuchen Sie die Plugin-Homepage"
msgid "Visit plugin homepage"
msgstr "Visite la página inicial del Plugin"
msgid "Visit plugin homepage"
msgstr "Visitez la page d'accueil du plugin"



#. translators: %s: plugin author
#. translators: %s: plugin author
#. translators: %s: plugin author
msgid "by %s"
msgstr "von %s"
msgid "by %s"
msgstr "por %s"
msgid "by %s"
msgstr "par %s"
```

I'm sure it has to do with async, but not sure what I doing wrong.

The basic code, I stripped out the translation logic

```
if (fs.existsSync(potFile)) {       
  var newPO = []
  var dirPath = path.resolve(languageDir)

  fs.readdir(dirPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err)
      this.log(err)
    else {
      files.forEach(file => {
        if (path.extname(file) === '.po') {
          const buffer = fs.readFileSync(languageDir + file, {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r'})
          const poArray = new Array(buffer.split('\n')).flat()

          var lineReader = require('line-reader')
          lineReader.eachLine(potFile, function (line, last) {
            // BUNCH OF TRANSLATION LOGIC
            // THAT ADDS LINES TO newPO ARRAY by:
            newPO.push(line)

            if (last) {
              // or check if it's the last one
              var newFile = fs.createWriteStream(languageDir + file + '.new')
              newFile.write(newPO.join('\n'))
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I thought it would spin up each .po as a separate block and they would all be isolated but guessing that's not how it works.

Hopefully, my code is not complete garbage but happy to hear what I'm doing wrong and what I could do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `var newPO = []` just above the `const buffer` line, to change the scope for that variable.

Right now it has this outer scope so you just keep appending to it and writing out the same array.

Comment: Perfect, that was it. I knew I had to be doing something daft. That's where I originally had it but move it at one point which was due to a different issue.  Thanks!